# Side-by-side monitor problem "2048x2048 max"

Tags: radeon, multiple-monitors

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, trying to configure side-by-side monitors

SystemSettings>Displays: I move the 2nd monitor to the right side

**The selected configuration for displays could not be applied**

Requested size (2880, 1024) exceeds 3D hardware limit (2048, 2048).
You must either rearrange the displays so that they fit within a (2048, 2048) square.

(underneath works, but I'd like to fix it to side-by-side.  PS: this hardware works in Windows 7)

`lspci | grep VGA`: (is this telling me I am using the "right" Radeon driver? (I do have a Radeon X600 video card))

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV370 [Radeon X600/X600 SE]
```

`xrandr`: (is this telling me I can use up to 4096x4096?)

```
    Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 1924, maximum 4096 x 4096
    DVI-0 connected primary 1280x1024+320+900 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
       1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0  
       1152x864       75.0  
       1024x768       75.1     60.0  
       800x600        75.0     60.3  
       640x480        75.0     60.0  
       720x400        70.1  
    DVI-1 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 432mm x 240mm
       1600x900       60.0*+
       1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
       1280x720       60.0  
       1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
       832x624        74.6  
       800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
       640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0  
       720x400        70.1
```

Earlier, Fabby asked about my GPU memory, is this what info is needed?

```
lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV370 [Radeon X600/X600 SE] [1002:5b62] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:0b02]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at fe9e0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    I/O ports at dc00 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at fea00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon

01:00.1 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV380 [Radeon X300/X550/X1050 Series] (Secondary) [1002:5b72]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:0b03]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
```

Comment: Well, this is not the **right** answer, but I just got a different video card, and so that solved the problem. Ok, maybe that **is** the right answer...